# How do I wait for a reply in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord

So what I want my bot to do is wait for a message from the user so when a user sends "!spec" the bot recieves that message and will respond with "See or Change?" then wait for you to type back "see" or "change" but I cant get it to wor. The docs aren't clear to me and I am not sure on how to do it.

This has to be able to work in PM as i dont want to spam the Discord with what i plan to do.

I have already tried this:

```js
    if (command === 'spec'){
            message.author.send("See or Change?");
            const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { time: 10000 });
            console.log(collector)
            collector.on('collect', message => {
                if (message.content === "See") {
                    message.channel.send("You Want To See Someones Spec OK!");
                } else if (message.content === "Change") {
                    message.channel.send("You Want To Change Your Spec OK!");
                }
            })
```

I may be writing this wrong. I am not used to the library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
    message.channel.send(`Are you sure to delete all data? \`YES\` / \`NO\``).then(() => {
      message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
          max: 1,
          time: 30000,
          errors: ['time']
        })
        .then(message => {
          message = message.first()
          if (message.content.toUpperCase() == 'YES' || message.content.toUpperCase() == 'Y') {
            message.channel.send(`Deleted`)
          } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == 'NO' || message.content.toUpperCase() == 'N') {
            message.channel.send(`Terminated`)
          } else {
            message.channel.send(`Terminated: Invalid Response`)
          }
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            message.channel.send('Timeout');
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 8):

Compare with == And Try.

```
if (command === 'spec'){
        message.author.send("See or Change?");
        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { time: 10000 });
        console.log(collector)
        collector.on('collect', message => {
            if (message.content == "See") {
                message.channel.send("You Want To See Someones Spec OK!");
            } else if (message.content == "Change") {
                message.channel.send("You Want To Change Your Spec OK!");
            }
        })
```

Comment: Doesn't see me replying "spec" after it sends "see or change"

Comment: did u try comparing with == ? please do the same if (command == 'spec')

Comment: it will send "see or change" it just doesnt seem to wait for the reply and just skips over the rest of it

Comment: m.author.id == message.author.id   tried here too ?

Comment: I cant exicute and check the part of the code given by you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152718/discussion-between-sindhoor-and-andy-wilson).

Comment: its using a npm plugin called discord.js

Comment: This is because you are using message.channel.send. It should be message.author.send because if you attempt to send the message to a channel, it doesn't know what you're talking about since a DM is not the same as a channel.