# How do I create a case statement in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This code is what i am using now to have a rough idea of what to do

```
bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if (messege.content.includes) {
        int (num = 0);
        switch(num) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println('The IP of the server is .');
            case 2:
                System.out.println('The Store is');
            case 3:
                System.out.println('Disord instant link : ');
            default:
                System.out.println('Sorry ');
        }
    }
});
bot.on('message', (message) => {
   if(message.content == (prefix + 'help')) {
        message.channel.sendMessage('With what may you like help?');
        message.reply('Enter 1, ...');
        message.reply('Enter 2, Stores link!');
        message.reply('Enter 3, discord instant link');
    }
});
```

How would i create a case statement based on what was given in the input and how to return the outcome?

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution? I'm a bit confused why you're using `System.out.println` -> This is a java function, but not javascript. Same with `int (num = 0);`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to look into `async / await` functions, so that on a message, you can run a certain function. [Tutorial on async/await](https://anidiotsguide.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/information/understanding-asyncawait.html)

Essentially you send the prompt:

`message.channel.send('With what may you like help?');`

then `await` to wait for a response and you can use the result in your switch statement.

Edit: You don't have to look into `async/await` consider using this solution: [Waiting for reply with discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45856621/8582663)