# How to execute a command when the timer is up

Tags: timer, bots, discord, discord.js

I've been working on this code recently which I found here:
[Discord.js reply to message then wait for reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856446/discord-js-reply-to-message-then-wait-for-reply)

I'd like to know if there is any way for the script to run a command when the timer goes off without any answer.

I've tried putting the command outside the code block of the collector
I've tried putting an `if (timer > 10000)`, which didn't work.

```js
if (command === 'spec') {
  message.author.send("See or Change?");
  const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, {
    time: 10000
  });
  console.log(collector);
  collector.on('collect', message => {
    if (message.content == "See") {
      message.channel.send("You Want To See Someones Spec OK!");
    } else if (message.content == "Change") {
      message.channel.send("You Want To Change Your Spec OK!");
    }
  });
}
```

When time ends I expect the script to change the nickname of the user who used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen to the [end event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector?scrollTo=e-end) of the Collector and check the size of the collected messages.

```js
collector.on('end', collected => {
  if (collected.size === 0) {
    // do something
  }
});
```