# waiting for reply gives error (time out) after reply. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot and I'm trying to create a bot in which you can adopt children (in my code you can get up to 5 children).

Now I have no idea if I'm even doing it the correct way but it looks like it should be working. I'm a kinda beginner in JS.
I found the code I'm using as example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64400392/16580567).

I then edited it to work with my code. The error I get is if the mentioned user answers with yes, my bot responds with "They didn't respond in time. try again later" while it should be "you're now adopted".

[image: image describing a problem]

Here is my code:

```js
else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}adopt`)) {
  
      let filter = m => m.author.id === message.mentions.users.first().id
      let marryEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed();
        marryEmbed.setDescription(mentioned.username + ', ' + randomadopt + `\`YES\` / \`NO\``)
        marryEmbed.setColor()
        marryEmbed.setTimestamp()
      message.channel.send(marryEmbed).then(() => {
      //console.log(rUser, rMentioned)
      message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 30000,
        errors: ['time']
      })
      .then(message => {
        message = message.first()
        if (message.content.toUpperCase() == 'YES' || message.content.toUpperCase() == 'Y') {
          let replyembed = new discord.MessageEmbed();
              replyembed.setColor()
              replyembed.setDescription(randomAdopted)
              replyembed.setTimestamp()
          if (!rUser.child1) {
            if(!rUser.partner){
              {code here}
            else{
              {code here}
            }
            
          }
          else if (!rUser.child2) {
            if(!rUser.partner){
              {code here}
            }
            else{
              {code here}
            }
          }
          
                
        } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == 'NO' || message.content.toUpperCase() == 'N') {
          let replyembed = new discord.MessageEmbed();
              replyembed.setColor()
              replyembed.setDescription('guess they\'ll stay homeless for a bit longer.')
              replyembed.setTimestamp()
          message.channel.send(replyembed)
          //message.reply('keep your head up, you\'re too good for them')
        } else {
          message.channel.send(`Terminated: Invalid Response`)
        }
      })
      .catch(collected => {
        let noreplyembed = new discord.MessageEmbed();
              noreplyembed.setColor()
              noreplyembed.setDescription('They didn\'t respond in time. try again later')
              noreplyembed.setTimestamp()
          message.channel.send(noreplyembed)
          console.log()
          //message.reply('No answer after 30 seconds, request canceled.');
      });
  })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce your code down to what's relevant to the question? There's way too much code to go through

Comment: I changed the code to a shorter variant without the less useful info. I don't know what is wrong with the code myself so I left most of it in

Comment: Did you set a string as `randomAdopted` in your code? It doesn't seem to be defined, but you did say you shortened your code.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox I deleted that out as Elitezen told me to delete irrelevant code.

Comment: What is `randomAdopted` then?

Comment: According to the edit history randomAdopted is a random element in an array of strings.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox as told by the other user, it's a random element in an array of strings.

Comment: My best guess is that there's an error inside of your `then` method that then triggers the `catch` method.

Comment: What Discord.js version are you using? Also, in your catch satement, log the error and post it here.